# Loading multiple images into screen without compressing and getting out of memory exception

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a screen which opens camera and takes photo and then it is retrieving that image from Bitmap and setting it on imageview. So in one screen i have 6 images. Because of bitmap i am getting

> out of memory exception

I tried compressing the photo but still 6 images memory size is more and compressing too much of the image reduces the quality.

Is there any other option other than bitmap to retrieve images put on the screen.

I have stored url of the image into database. Is there anything i can do with url and without bitmap.?

I am new to android development please somebody help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by " compressing too much of the image"?  Instead of "compressing", do you mean "reducing the resolution"?

Comment: yes,If you have any server side implementation then you can load your image directly from server to your image view.OR if you don't have server side then you should compress it with .png format.

Comment: mbeckish ya reducing the resolution, it reduces the quality. So i do not want to reduce quality of image.

Comment: no it is android app so images will be stored in SDcard. I am storing that url into database.